# ¿Cómo puedo arreglar mi Diagrama E/R?

Tags: base-de-datos, diagrama-er

Apenas estoy comenzando a aprender los fundamentos de bases de datos por lo que comencé con los diseños conceptuales, hice este ejercicio:

*Una empresa desea llevar el control de todo su ganado. A lo largo y ancho del pais cuenta con ranchos, los ranchos están organizados por ciudad, estados y regiones. Una ciudad pertenece a un estado y un estado pertenece a una región. Cada rancho está localizado en una zona donde predomina un tipo de clima, en cada rancho existen una o mas secciones dentro las cuales se encuentra el ganado, cada ejemplar pertenece a una de las secciones, pertenece a una raza, tiene un peso, fecha de nacimiento, sexo, número de registro, nombre, costo, altura anterior, altura posterior y color. De cada ejemplar si es nacido en el rancho se desea saber quien es su padre y quien es su madre (los cuales tambien son otro ejemplar), para todos los ejemplares se desea saber qué vacunas se le han aplicado y la fecha de aplicación.*

Hice mi diagrama E/R  pero no sé cómo podría realizar de forma correcta las siguientes dos partes del enunciado:

***De cada ejemplar si es nacido en el rancho se desea saber quien es su padre y quien es su madre (los cuales también son otro ejemplar)***.

***Cada rancho está localizado en una zona donde predomina un tipo de clima***. A lo de "zona", ¿se refiere a la región?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El de los ejemplares seria una tabla recursiva, y el tema del rancho es parte de una composición, o sea una zona contiene muchos ranchos, y cada zona tiene un atributo de tipo_clima. solo debes realizar los enlaces correspondientes entre tus entidades.

Comment: @Santiago yo diría que como aún estamos hablando de entidades y no aún de tablas (análisis, no diseño), sería más bien una relación involutiva o recursiva.

Comment: @TomuRain , Seguramente que si, solo que su diagrama, representa un diagrama de datos y no así un diagrama conceptual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qué bueno que estés aprendiendo! Hiciste un buen intento, espero poder ayudarte;
el secreto para hacer el diagrama de la forma más precisa es desglosar el enunciado oración por oración.

*Aclaración: Esto es totalmente orientativo de la estructura del diagrama. Siéntete libre de modificar el formato del diagrama, el modo de mostrar las cardinalidades, los otros campos que no están en el enunciado pero agregaste (está bien!), etc.*

### Enunciado

> **Una empresa desea llevar el control de todo su ganado.**

Meramente introductorio, no aporta nada relevante al diagrama.

> **A lo largo y ancho del pais cuenta con ranchos, los ranchos están organizados por ciudad, estados y regiones. Una ciudad pertenece a un estado y un estado pertenece a una región.**

Ahí tenemos las siguientes relaciones:

- Una región tiene de 0 a n estados.
- Un estado tiene de 0 a n ciudades.
- Una ciudad tiene de 0 a n ranchos.

[image: Figura 1]

> **Cada rancho está localizado en una zona donde predomina un tipo de clima.**

De manera general, una región es sinónimo de zona. Pero si en el ejercicio utiliza la palabra zona, es porque es una entidad diferente a región. Entonces:

- Una zona tiene de 0 a n ranchos.
- Un clima puede predominar de 0 a n zonas.

[image: Figura 2]

> **En cada rancho existen una o mas secciones dentro las cuales se encuentra el ganado, cada ejemplar pertenece a una de las secciones, pertenece a una raza, tiene un peso, fecha de nacimiento, sexo, número de registro, nombre, costo, altura anterior, altura posterior y color.**

Entonces:

- Un rancho tiene entre 1 a n secciones (dato importante de cardinalidad: te están diciendo que debe tener al menos 1 sección).
- Una sección tiene entre 0 a n ejemplares.
- Una raza puede pertenecer a entre 0 a n ejemplares.
- Un color puede pertenecer a entre 0 a n ejemplares. (para mejorar el diagrama coloqué COLOR como entidad, ya que a diferencia de los otros atributos, pueden ser seteados y usados por múltiples ejemplares. Esto es totalmente opcional, puedes colocarlo como atributo.)
- Un ejemplar tiene los siguientes atributos: peso, fecha de nacimiento, sexo, número de registro, nombre, costo, altura anterior, altura posterior.

[image: Figura 3]

> **De cada ejemplar si es nacido en el rancho se desea saber quien es su padre y quien es su madre (los cuales tambien son otro ejemplar)**

Acá hay una trampa y es que hay una relación involutiva: una relación que se relaciona consigo misma.

- Un ejemplar puede (o no) tener un ejemplar madre (0 o 1).
- Un ejemplar puede (o no) tener un ejemplar padre (0 o 1).

Obviamente todos los ejemplares tienen padres, pero estamos realizando una abstracción y hablando del contexto del problema.

'EjemplarPadres' es una tabla que terminarás teniendo en la base de datos cuando realices el diagrama de clases, pero por el momento NO es una entidad.

[image: Figura 4]

> **Para todos los ejemplares se desea saber qué vacunas se le han aplicado y la fecha de aplicación.**

Vamos a crear la relación "Vacunación" con un campo fecha, (aunque en el gráfico utilice el mismo cuadrito... me entiendes).

- Un ejemplar puede recibir entre 0 a vacunaciones.
- Un tipo de vacuna puede ser usada para entre 0 y n vacunaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda que los diagramas de entidad relación si bien se intenta que sean lo más representativo posibles y existen especificaciones precisas de UML, la verdad es que hay infinidad de formas de hacerlos de manera aceptada. Lo importante es que quien lo reciba, lo comprenda y no lo malinterprete. Para ello es una buena práctica acompañarlo con una especificación redactada.